# Is there a way to send firebase push notification to both iOS and android using nodejs?

Tags: android, ios, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have written this code with nodejs to send a push notification from a nodejs server to a specific user of a mobile application:

```
const { admin } = require("../config/Firebase");

const sendNotification = async (req, res) => {
  const requestBody = req?.body;
  const registrationToken = requestBody?.registrationToken; // get it from mobile app

  const data = {
    message: {
      token: registrationToken,
      notification: {
        title: "Notification Title",
        body: "Notification Body ",
        description: "Notification description",
      },
      android: {
        notification: {
          imageUrl: "https://foo.bar.pizza-monster.png",
        },
      },
      apns: {
        payload: {
          aps: {
            "mutable-content": 1,
          },
        },
        fcm_options: {
          image: "https://foo.bar.pizza-monster.png",
        },
      },
      webpush: {
        headers: {
          image: "https://foo.bar.pizza-monster.png",
        },
      },

      data: {
        Nick: "Mario",
        Room: "PortugalVSDenmark",
      },
    },
  };

  try {
    admin.messaging().send(data.message);
    res.status(200).json({ notificationStatus: "success" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error while sending notification: ", error);
    res.status(500).json({ notificationStatus: "failed" });
  }
};
```

But it works only for android devices. So i would like to know if there a config or something like that which makes the server sends it to both iOS and android devices ?

Comment: Tokens for diff devices are different. You can not send a push notification to 2 separate devices using only one token.

Comment: @Fawkes i know i didn't mean to send it to two different devices. But let's assume i have an android or iOS device, does this script allows me to send it to one of them ?

Comment: It should. When you send a notification, you will get logs from FCM. Can you please share logs on what is the reason for the failure?